# Likelihood ratio test when adding data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

Suppose I fit the following models using MLE:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Model }1 & & y = b_1x+b_2 (d+\cos(\theta)) + \epsilon \\[6pt]
\text{Model }2 & & y = b_1x+b_2 d + \epsilon \quad \quad \quad \quad \ \ \ \\[6pt]
\end{matrix}$$

In the models, $b_1$ and $b_2$ are estimated parameters.  Terms $y$, $d$, and $\theta$ are data, but only $y$ enters the likelihood for MLE. So, the second model is a case of the first model where $\cos(\theta) = 0$ (i.e. $\theta = \pi/2$).  Given that $\theta$ is data, is it valid to use a likelihood-ratio test to compare the models?

Answer (score 5):

**No, it is not valid:** Since $\theta$ is part of the observed data, you simply have to look at this value to see whether or not $\cos \theta = 0$.  There is no statistical test for this hypothesis, since it is determined (with certainty) from looking at the data.  In fact, your models are not different models at all.  The second stipulates *a data value*, not a parametric difference in the model form.

(**Secondary note:** It is customary in statistical modelling to use English letters for observed data and Greek letters for unobserved parameters.  In order to conform to that convention, and avoid any unecessary confusion, I would suggest you change the notation $\theta$ to, say, $w$.  That way it will be obvious that the value is part of the observable data.)

Comment: In this case, $\theta$ is data. However, $\theta$ is difficult to measure, so there is a question of it is worth the effort to measure $\theta$ or if assuming $\theta$ is 90° is "good enough."

Comment: You will need to be a bit clearer on what you mean by "difficult to measure".  In statistical parlance, "data" refers to the observable values, which means that we know their actual values.  If you have a quantity that is difficult to measure, it wouuld be usual to frame that as an unobserved value $w$, and then stipulate that you observe $w + \varepsilon$.  In any case, that which is observed is known; that which is unobserved is inferred.